# JavaScript funcions doesn't works in WebViews in Android Jelly Beans and below

Tags: javascript, android, webview, epub, android-4.1-jelly-bean

In an Android application I'm trying to display an EPUB book through WebView. For navigate the book I'm using [EPUBJS](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/), and [Pure Drawer](http://mac81.github.io/pure-drawer/) for some visual effects. When I run my application in devices witch use Android KitKat(4.4) version or above this works fine, but if I try below versions like Jelly Beans(4.3). Some features of `Epub.js` doesn't work, for example `Book.prev`, `Book.next`, `Book.goto(url)` and `Book.renderTo()` while other features like `Book.getToc()` and `Book.getMetadata()` still work fine, and I can get all books chapters.

I put all the code in an javascript file as follow

```
function init_js_code(url){
               var Book = ePub(url, { restore: true});
               Book.getMetadata().then(function(meta){
                  document.title = meta.bookTitle;

              });
              $( "#next" ).click(function() {
                    Book.nextPage();
              });
              $( "#prev" ).click(function() {
                    Book.prevPage();
              });

              Book.getToc().then(function(toc){
                var $select = document.getElementById("toc"),
                    $docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                var cList = $('ul.nav-primary');
                toc.forEach(function(chapter) {
                  // logic to create a menu
                });

              });
              Book.ready.all.then(function(){
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
              });
              Book.renderTo("area");
```

In html file there is just a call to this function

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script>
          function getPDFURL(){
                 ...
          }

          var url = 'http://' + getPDFURL() + '.epub';
          init_js_code(url);
    </script>
</body>
```

The html code is rendered in activity this way

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            ..
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/.../index.html?url="+material_url);
```

Although what cold be the problem, some Javascript functions are blocked in this devices?
There are any another way to it?

Comment: `4.4` simply has a LOT more html5/js features than `4.3` and before, the code is using one or more of those web platform features.